# PDO/MYSQL prepared statements not escaping characters?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm trying to write power a search function in my program:

```
$search = "%".$_POST['search']."%";
$query=$connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN LIKE ?");
$query->execute(array($search));
```

However, it seems that users can simply enter % and it returns all results. How do I prevent this from happening? I was under the impression that using prepared statements would have escaped these characters. Does this apply to other characters (\, ', etc) as well? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Prepared statements don't escape anything. When you prepare a statement, your query gets precompiled, so that it only needs the placeholders ( `?` ) to be filled in. Since theres no way to change the SQL of precompiled query, no escaping is needed.

To fix this, escape `%` and `_` manually.

Added:

A bit of common sense reasoning: In your case, when a user enters `%` into a searchbox, your `$search` variable contains string `%%%`. How would MySQL know, which `%` it should escape, and which it should leave alone?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to protect against the inclusion of `%` or `_` in your application code if you don't want it as valid input.

```
if (strpos($_POST['search'], '%') !== FALSE || strpos($_POST['search'], '_') !== FALSE) {
  $query = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN LIKE ?");
  $query->execute(array($search));
}
else echo "% and _ are not allowed!";
```

As for characters like `'`, they're treated as part of the string passed in place of the `?` placeholder, not concatenated in to build a SQL statement. So they are safe.

Answer (score 0):

You must properly escape user input, to let the server know which characters are wildcards, and which are data to match.

```
$search = '%' . str_replace(array('_', '%'), array('\\_', '\\%'), $_POST['search']) . '%';
```

This will escape those characters that would otherwise be considered wildcards. `$search` would now contain something along the lines of:

```
%100\%%
```

which will match `I always give 100% when working` but not `I do 100 pushups daily`.